# Could not load file or assembly. MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

First time user of MVC 4 EF 5 on Visual studio 2012 with c#.  I have just opened the project on another computer.

I get the following error message please help as I am a bit out of my depth.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Could not load file or assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' or one of its dependencies.
  The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.
  Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' or one of its dependencies.
  The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request.
  Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = MBRONET\m1105825
LOG: DisplayName = ThumbBusters[Conflict]
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: ThumbBusters[Conflict] | Domain ID: 3
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///I:/Desktop/ThumbBusters/ThumbBusters/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = I:\Desktop\ThumbBusters\ThumbBusters\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: I:\Desktop\ThumbBusters\ThumbBusters\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: I:\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/m1105825/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cdf649a7/f0e924b3/ThumbBusters[Conflict].DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/m1105825/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/cdf649a7/f0e924b3/ThumbBusters[Conflict]/ThumbBusters[Conflict].DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///I:/Desktop/ThumbBusters/ThumbBusters/bin/ThumbBusters[Conflict].DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: NAME
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.
```

Stack Trace:

```
[FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath) +258
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +135
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9873912
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +254
```

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.17929

Comment: This should not have been closed.  User provide clear error messages and we have a proposed answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Could not load file or assembly 'ThumbBusters[Conflict]' or one of its dependencies. **The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference**

On the other computer, you have a `ThumbBusters` DLL which is not the same as the one you had on the previous computer. Thus, your project is unable to load it.

You should check and make sure to bring over the right version of the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

There's your problem: "I have just opened the project on another computer."

Whatever you used to load the project on the other computer must not have that `ThumbBusters` DLL in with the project, or installed on the machine. That's something that you're going to have to look into. If it's something from nuGet, that's easy enough to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I went into the bin folder and deleted the conflict file and this resolved the issue.